# building a c++ project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to import and build a c++ project in eclipse Juno on ubuntu.
The problem that I'm facing is that the build fails because it does not include the paths properly so I did:

1: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options: Enable "Automate discovery paths and symbols"
2: Project -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols: Add any necessary include paths

and added the folders, but when I rebuild, it still complains about my

```
#include "myfile.h"
```

where myfile.h is in a mySubDirectory and mySubDirectory is added to the include path.
Also I guess there is supposed to be a symbol.xml but I do not think there exists one.
Any ideas?

**New discoveries**: I noticed that when I created a brand new project, I had an "includes" link in the project explorer but when importing, I did not have that link, so I tried recreating the project instead of importing.
Also, I had to correct the build path.
Now, I get this error:
No rule to make target MainEntry.cpp needed by 'main'
and here is my make file:

```
LIB=
INC=
all: main

main:   MainEntry.cpp
        g++ -Wall $(LIB) $(INC) MainEntry.cpp -o bin/main_output
clean:
        rm -r bin/*
```

Also, I noticed that when I right click on the makefile, the "build selected file" option is grayed out.

I figured out that instead of changing the build path in "build command", if you actually change the "build directory" setting in properties, then it works.

Is it better to have separate make files in separate folders or a single makefile with several targets?
Having multiple ones would require you to change the build path in eclipse when building another folder which is irritating.

Comment: And you're sure that you entered the correct path? If you take a look at the Console view when you build your project you should be able to see the build commands with the full include paths (`-I"blahblah"`).

Comment: You should add what paths you actually listed and where your file is located -- it's quite possible one is mistyped or points to a parent/child directory when CDT expects something else.

Comment: Did you check that case of the filename? `"MyFile.h" vs. "myfile.h"`

Comment: I think you can remove MainEntry.cpp from the rule for main. Main does depend on MainEntry.cpp, and you don't have a rule for that. But if you leave it out, the g++ command line will execute which will build the program if the instruction is correct. Other solution could be to give a wildcard build rule for all cpp files. These are makefile issues.

Comment: I see. I do not specifically care whether or not to use makefiles. What I want to accomplish is to be able to compile/debug/run cross-compile our c code in eclipse. Anymore guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, eclipse can only compile/run code with with make files. Either your own  makefiles or it can auto generate the make files. Right?